# Problema con for en excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Una consulta estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de diagnostico en excel con  vba , aunque ya lo termine, tengo un problema con la cantidad de codigo

```
introducir el código aquí
Dim ulcera, wil, dbt As String
Dim valor, valor1, i As Integer
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If txt4.Text = "x" Then
dbt = "25%"
Else
dbt = ""
End If
If txt5.Text = "x" Then
dbt = "25%"
End If
If txt7.Text = "x" Then
dbt = "25%"
End If
If txt8.Text = "x" Then
dbt = "25%"
End If
txtdiabetes = dbt
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno solo puse una parte del código , porque es muy extenso y el punto es que al marcar un texbox con una x , este tendrá un porcentaje hasta llegar a 100 o la cantidad marcada , son 3 efermedades , pero me di cuenta que la cantidad de codigo es demasiada y tendria problemas si aumentan las enfermedades o los sintomas , entonces quisiera saber como puedo recorrer los texbox usando un for y sumarlos , quise usar controls , pero mi excel no lo reconoce, gracias ...

Answer (score 2):

Para tu caso pienso que sería más útil un `For Each` en lugar del `For` tradicional. La sintaxis es sencilla:

```
For Each elemento [ As tipo ] In conjunto
    ' Instrucciones
Next [ elemento ]
```

Este ciclo lo que hace es repetirse una vez por cada elemento que posee un conjunto. Lo que está entre corchetes son partes opcionales. Ahora explicaré sus partes:

`conjunto` es una serie de objetos o una variable que los contenga.
En `elemento` se encuentra el elemento actual de `conjunto`.
`tipo` es el tipo de la variable `elemento`, como los que usas para declarar otras variables.

Dentro del ciclo, puedes escribir 2 instrucciones especiales, `Exit For` para salir del ciclo y `Continue For` para saltarte una iteración.

Por último, habrá casos en los que tengas que usar un `For Each` dentro de otro. Aunque no es necesario, te puede ayudar a diferenciarlos escribiendo de nuevo la variable `elemento` luego de `Next`.

Te dejo un ejemplo para iterar sobre un rango de celdas:

```
For Each celda In Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
    celda.Value = "Hola" 
Next
```

También puedes indagar más en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) o buscar un tutorial.